# Codeblocks Build error

Tags: gcc, codeblocks, build-error

I'm using Codeblocks 13.12 with MinGW on Winodows 10. I'm somewhat familiar with C, but haven't been coding for some while. Last time I wrote a code was with Turbo compiler. So I'm starting to code once again and this the first time I'm using GCC. So I thought of starting with a simple code to print the pattern:[Pattern to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddRA6.jpg)

The code I wrote is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    for(i;i<=4;++i)
    {
        j=2*i+1;
        for(k=1;k<=j;++k)
            printf(k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:[Error on build attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGfBU.jpg)

Tell me, is it because of some error in my code(not logical), or there's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all there is no space after the include.
EDIT: Tried it, and it works with no space, but it's better for further reading

second, using namespace is not C, it is C++,

third, the **printf** function has to look like this: `printf("%i",k);` there has to be placeholders for each variable you want to print. please see some turorial and don't mix C and C++. If you want to program in C++ use something like `cout >>` instead of printf and use the C++-Headers, `#include <stdio>`

That works and is good to read ;-):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    for(i;i<=4;++i)
    {
        j=2*i+1;
        for(k=1;k<=j;++k)
            printf("%i\n",k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It says undefined reference to print.

Comment: I added a working example to my answer. It compiles and runs under Linux. And the undefined reference to print is because there is no print function in stdio.h. The function you are trying to use is called print**f**

Comment: Yeah it just worked. In your answer you've written 'print' instead of 'printf'.